# Access variable from outside function (PHP)

Tags: php

I am trying to access this variable into function but its give me an error `Undefined variable: ERROR`.

```
<?php
$ERROR["emptyEmail"] = "empyt email";
$ERROR["emptyPassword"] = "empty password";

function validateLogin($data) {
    if (empty($data["email"])) {
        return $ERROR["emptyEmail"];
    } else if (empty($data["password"])) {
        return $ERROR["emptyPassword"];
    } else {
        return "valid";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: If it's just a lookup map, why not make it a constant?  They have global scope.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Insert this inside the function:

```
global $ERROR;
```

So, the variable can be accessed inside the function scope (see [global keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global)).

```
function validateLogin($data) {
    global $ERROR;
    ...
}
```

Alternatively you can access to all variables that are outside the function using [$GLOBALS](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php):

```
$GLOBALS['ERROR']
```